# Look up the size of specific subfolders

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I'm having difficulty understand what it wrong with a bash shell that should look up subfolder sizes.

I have a folder within which are many subfolders. Some of these subfolders are called "PARENT", and inside these folders are images. I want to run a shell that will look up each of the PARENT folders and give me the total file size. I've pieced together a bash shell that should do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/STUDIO-COMPLETE/ARCHIVE/01_JIRA_TICKETS/2018/01_2018 \
    -type d -iname parent \
    -exec du -sm {} \; > All_Parent_2018.csv
```

This should look up each PARENT subfolder, find the disk usage of each and output the results to a CSV file. At first I thought it had worked. However, I've noticed that in actual fact the number of MB it finds is corresponding to the number of files in each subfolder, not the actual size.

For example, many of these folders come out at exactly 2.0MB, 2 being the number of files in that specific folder. Another returned 291MB, it has 291 files in it. I have no idea why it's doing this. `-du` literally translates as Disk Usage so I don't know why it would be counting files instead.

Comment: Use `-exec du -sm {} \;` (without the nested `find` command) and try again.

Comment: @Socowi It still happens even without ```find``` (which incidentally I pasted here by accident, ```find``` causes the script to error). What's strange is that the first few folders in the CSV do list the actual MB of each folder, but at line 8 it starts to list the file count. The folders are located on a Azure cloud server, I wonder if that's having an impact?

Comment: What if you specify `/usr/bin/du -sm`?

Comment: Or (if this is GNU du) try: `du -sm -- {} \;`, i.e. with `--` to signal the 'end of option arguments' to du.

Comment: Reading your question again I noticed that there is no evidence that the reported numbers are wrong. Sure, it's very suspicious that 219 files sum up to 291MB but that doesn't mean it has to be wrong. Please determine the correct values manually and compare them to your results.

Comment: @Roadowl Unfortunately neither of these make a difference. Tried each separately, and together.

Comment: @Socowi True. I'll take one folder as an example. It is listed on the CSV output as being 76MB. In Finder it's the file count that is 76. The total disk usage for the folder is 1.13GB (1,130,476,414 bytes) which is closer to what I'd expect it to be. There's no way that folder is only 76MB. I've checked many folders in this way and they're all following the same pattern. Only the first 8 rows of the CSV count the disk usage correctly, the rest are counting the number of files. It's like it's failing at some point to count disk usage and starts counting files.

Comment: Thank you for confirming the problem. Maybe you could attract more people if you can boil down the problem. Is the `find -exec` part really necessary or can the problem also be observed with a single `du -sm /path/to/dir`? Maybe you could make the problem reproducible (at least for OS X users). Write a small script that generates a scenario like yours and add it to your answer after you verified the problem again. For instance `mkdir d; head -c 2m /dev/zero > d/a; head -c 3m /dev/zero > d/b; du -sm d # expected 5 but prints 2`